# What is the fastest way in vim to change a period "." to an arrow "->"?

Tags: vim

I know this is going to sound like a nit-picky question that isn't very important, but it actually proves to be a source of frustration for me.

Occasionally I will use the dot operator "." on a pointer type when I meant to use an arrow "->".  To fix it, I usually need to change just 2-3 dots to arrows, but I can't seem to find a way to do this in vim that doesn't take a relatively large amount of keystrokes for the amount of text I am changing.

For example, I could do:

```
:lineNum,lineNum s/\<objectName\>\./->/g
```

But that is quite a lot of typing if there are only 2-3 instances.

Alternatively, I can use `jkhl` to navigate to each period, and do:

```
r-a><ESC>
```

But five keystrokes for each one seems like torture after using `jkhl` to find all three, as well as the mental context switch that comes with entering and exiting insert mode so quickly.

How do you change your dots into arrows?  Have you found a method that is faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/\.<CR>
s-><ESC>
n.
n.
```

... etc ...

each `n` goes no the next expression you searched for, and each `.` repeats the substitution of the dot with an arrow. mix and match ns and dots as needed.

Comment: @CoryKlein that's what I was getting at, use `s` rather than `x`. +1

Comment: This might be more useful as `:%s/\./->/gc`

Comment: @Conner: yes, I'd agree, but OP wanted just 2-3 changes in a local area. Substituting over the whole file will end up with a lot of false positives, and working out the line range to apply over might be too much like hard work :)

Comment: Oftentimes a refactor makes such a change necessary.  A nice way to hone in on the particular object that you care about is to put it into the search too and then `\zs` to define where you want the cursor left, e.g. `/myobj\zs\.`  Then the cursor will be on the dot, but only on dots following "myobj".

Answer (score 4):

you can map a key for example:

```
:map v :s/\./->/g^M
```

Then just press the key v on that line.

Comment: visual mode is often quite useful (depending on how you use vim). I would use something like `g.` so as not to block vim functionality but the key mapped is obviously up to OP.

Answer (score 1):

First search for an initial instance of the dot: `/\.`.

Do the replacement on the first instance with the cursor on the dot that needs to change, using <kbd>s</kbd>, which kills the current character and begins insertion: `s->`.

Now use <kbd>n</kbd> to find the next match, and period to repeat the last command: <kbd>.</kbd>

If you need to be more specific about the dots, then your search could be: `/objectName\./e`, leaving the cursor at the end of the search, but that's more typing. Perhaps `/ob/e+9`?

Comment: I like this idea, but it doesn't work.  First of all, you need to search `\/.`, and secondly, when I repeat the command using `.`, the dot doesn't get deleted.  I'm not sure why.  I'm supposed to hit `<ESC>` after `xi->`, right?

Comment: bah . repeat only does the insert, sorry

Answer (score 1):

if you are using vim, you can add keyboard mapping to your ~/.vimrc file, something like :

```
map <F2> :lineNum,lineNum s/\<objectName\>\./->/g
```

then when you type "F2" in vim, the mapped command appears and you can edit parameters before fireing it.

Answer (score 1):

With the cursor on the pointer name hit `*`. This will find all instances of the pointer.
Then `/<M-UP>\./e` will retrieve the previous search, append `.` and place the cursor on the `.`.
Now our search term will only find the problem `.`s.
On the first one `s-><ESC>` replaces the `.` with the `->` as requested and `n.` will fix all other occurrences

Because `n.` is used so often I find it helpful to map it, I use `F3`

```
map <F3> n.
```

Comment: I think this is a great method as well.  However, when I search for `/foo\./\e`, my cursor doesn't get placed on the period given the text `foo.bar()`, instead it gets placed on the `f`.

Comment: Lose the backslash before the 'e'.  I believe this was a mistake.

Comment: yup the backslash was a typo. should work better now. `/e` places the cursor at the end of the search term.   
see `:help pattern` for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can select -> in visual mode and do `"ky` to save it into register k and then go over the . and do `x"kP`

Comment: `x"kP` needs to actually be `xh"kP`